# Copying an image within my Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows Phone Application in C# and on my application page i have an image object that is currently filled with an image. However i have another image object on the same page as well as a button object. What i want to do it click the button, and once i have done so i want to copy the image from the filled image object and paste it into the blank object.

Is there a way of doing this, i read something about the use of a bitmap to do so but i'm not sure how to do it? Any examples or ideas of what code i could use would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remember `Image.Source` and pass that to the other page and set it as a source for another `image` control.

It also depends on how you are filling the first `Image` control. If you are in the control of filling both controls, then you can just as easy use *the same code* to fill both controls.

Comment: Hi, i guess i should've explained it bit more, the i want to copy the image without repeating the source because the first picture is being cropped and then stored in memory, it is this part i want to copy across

Comment: How did you crop that image in the first place? If you did that, you have the original image as well.

Comment: I have written some code where the user draws around the part of the image that they want to crop, the user then presses copy and it returns it as an image, i then want to be able to give a new image object the value of this new image of what the user has cropped

Comment: But *you* wrote that code and *you* have the original image. Just don't discard it.

Comment: But i don't want to use the original image, i want to use the cropped image stored in memory as a new image, it is that that i want to copy and paste into the blank image object

Comment: Have you implemented the cropping? Or is that the thing you are looking for?